# Matlab GUI Callback Start and Completion

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

Is there a general purpose way to determine when a Matlab GUI callback function begins and then has returned to the dispatcher?

I want to lock out user interaction while callbacks are running to completion and also show busy status while callbacks are running. Is there a dispatcher accessible where I can insert this code, or do I have to put it into every callback function.

I am aware of the modal *waitbar* but I want to avoid using that as much as possible. (They can't be killed gracefully.)

Comment: I tried the following improvisation that adds wrapper function to each callback: `A = findall(0, 'Type', 'UIControl');`  `for i = 1:length(A)`      `set(A(i), 'Callback', {@wrapper, A(i).Callback});`  `end`.

Comment: When wrapper function is:  `function wrapper(ObjH, EventData, origCallback)`  `disp('Wrapper called!');`  `feval(origCallback, ObjH, EventData);`

Comment: I think if you want a piece of code which execute whenever any callback runs you will have to implement the dispatcher yourself: All callbacks point to the same dispatcher function (with one identifier argument). The dispatcher display "busy" then call the actual intended callback function. When the function return to the dispatcher, you display "ready" then return ... In case multiple callbacks can be fired simultaneously, you will have to watch [re-entrancy](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/controlling-callback-re-entrancy) cases ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to add a wrapper function, that wraps all original UIControl callback functions.
The wrapper function does the following:

- Locks (disables) all GUI UIControl objects.
- Executes original callback function.
- Enables all GUI UIControl after original callback returns.

You can also start a timer before original callback, and stop the timer when callback returns (the timer can simulate a wait bar using an image built int to the main GUI [image inside a small axes]).

Example (assuming GUI was created using `guide` tool):

```
% --- Executes just before untitled1 is made visible.
function untitled1_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to untitled1 (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for untitled1
handles.output = hObject;

%Add wrapper function to each UIControl callback.
A = findall(hObject.Parent, 'Type', 'UIControl');
for i = 1:length(A)
    set(A(i), 'Callback', {@wrapper, A(i).Callback});
end

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes untitled1 wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


function wrapper(ObjH, EventData, origCallback)
disp('Do somthing before callback begins...');
%You can also start a timer.

%Disable all UIControl objects, before executing original callback
A = findall(ObjH.Parent, 'Type', 'UIControl');
for i = 1:length(A)
    set(A(i), 'Enable', 'off');
end

%Execute original callback.
feval(origCallback, ObjH, EventData);

disp('Do somthing after callback ends...');
%You can also stop the timer.

%Enable all UIControl objects, after executing original callback
for i = 1:length(A)
    set(A(i), 'Enable', 'on');
end


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
pause(1);
set(handles.pushbutton1, 'BackgroundColor', [rand(1,1), rand(1,1), rand(1,1)]);
```

Comment: This worked well. Thanks for showing the complete solution.

Comment: I made one change. Instead of **A = findall(hObject, 'Type', 'UIControl');**, I used **A = findall(hObject.Parent, 'Type', 'UIControl');** This is what is needed to disable all of the UICONTROLs.

Comment: I modified the example, thank's. Remark: I originally used **findall(0, 'Type', 'UIControl');**

Answer (score 0):

You can generally lock user interaction with the `waitfor` command. It is designed to do exactly what you ask.

You can make your callback function update a handle property when it's finished, which can cause `waitfor` to exit. If that handle property you're updating also happens to hold the result of a `tic / toc` operation timing the duration of your callback function, then you kill two birds with one stone :)

Comment: `waitfor` is pretty straightforward ... but happy to provide an example if this isn't clear.