# Matlab, update reference to main gui object in sub gui

Tags: matlab, user-interface

## Situation

We have a fairly large GUI project made in GUIDE. It connects to a piece of hardware via different interfaces (serial, lan etc), for that we have interface classes. The main gui selects the interface object, configures it and and saves it in `handles.int`. The different interface classes implement a common set of methods inherited from a common base class, so all functions of the GUI don't need to know what kind of interface we have.

We also have subguis. They get the current `handles.int` passed to them when they are opened and saved in the subgui's own `handles.int`

## Problem

When we switch the interface in the main gui while a subgui is open, the handle in the subgui still point to an old interface that is now no longer active, it does not get updated when we change handles.int to be a different object.

We either need a reference in the subguis that gets updated when it object in the main function changes, or we need to get the subguis to update their interface reference every time an interface is accessed from there.

## Solutions I tried

We can update the handle in the subgui every time we access the interface, like so:

```matlab
main_handles = guidata(findobj('Tag','main_gui'));
main_handles.int.do_something();
```

That would mean a lot of refactoring however, as the existing GUI uses `handles.int` in all places.

## Questions

Is there a way to build a single callback which gets executed on every button press in the subgui, before the actual callback? If so, we could get the current interface from the main GUI in that callback.

Another posiblity I see would be to update the interface reference in the subguis from within the main gui every time the interface is switched.

Are there any other solutions? Is there a way to pass the main gui's `handles.int` to the subgui so that it gets automatically updated in the subgui when we change it in the main gui?

Comment: In case you need "single callback which gets executed on every button press", check the answer I posted back in 2016: [Matlab GUI Callback Start and Completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797930/matlab-gui-callback-start-and-completion/38802673#38802673)

Comment: @Rotem that looks very promissing, thank you. I'll look into this.